# C++ regular expression from ReadProcessMemory output

Tags: c++, regex, tr1, readprocessmemory

I want to match some strings from notepad process memory, but i have no success.
Here is the code:

```
int bytes_to_read = (int)info.RegionSize;
char *buffer;
buffer = (char*)malloc(bytes_to_read+1);
ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, info.BaseAddress, buffer, bytes_to_read, NULL);
const char *t1re = ";\\d{0,19}";
regex ret1(t1re);
cmatch match;

if(regex_search(buffer, match, ret1))
{
    cout << "Found: " << pe32.szExeFile << "\n";
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: "I have no success" means........?

Comment: What are the strings you are trying to match? And which strings are actually matched? (Examples?)

Comment: for example, i type in notepad test;123456789 but the program does not match the string: ";123456789".

Comment: Did you try to debug your program, to make sure that buffer actually contained the string you expect?

Comment: i am sure that the buffer contains the string that i expect.

Answer (score 0):

notepad, being a Windows program, probably uses UCS-2 or I guess these days UTF-16. Which means you need a Unicode regex.

And are you sure that regex_search even works on binary data? It might exit at the first zero byte believing it is the end of string.

Comment: What can i do in order to work for me? Can you give me more details, please?

Comment: @user3092064: I know that my answer is not the best because it doesn't solve anything. However, I don't have time to research it. You will need to go figure it out.

Comment: it works with this code, but i cannot imagine what i am doing wrong.    const char *expr = ";\\d{0,19}";
  regex rgx(expr);
  cmatch match;
  const char *tgt = "This is a test.23ed;1234567890fdfh0987654321?qwef32f3f";
  if (regex_search(tgt, match, rgx))
    cout << "Match found after";
  else
    cout << "Not found.";
  system("pause");